# Meaning of equation in pure exchange economy

Tags: microeconomics

I do not know the step Xa=20-xa
The economy has 20Xa, so what does this step mean?
In my view, replacing Xb should be 40-20Xa

[image]

Comment: Hi! Please avoid unnecessary tags (like finance here). Also provide text that enables future visitors to find the question with the right keywords, making the question useful. Finally, please use MathJax to type in your equations. There is a cheatsheet  for it in the meta section of our site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $X_A$ denotes the number of goods $X$ consumed by $A$, whereas $X_B$ denotes the number of goods $X$ consumed by $B$, and the economy has a total of 20 goods, it makes sense that
$$
X_A + X_B = 20.
$$
(Consuming less would be feasible but suboptimal.) We can rearrange this to
$$
X_A = 20 - X_B.
$$
From the equality of the MRSs you have $X_A = X_B$, hence
$$
X_A = 20 - X_A.
$$

Answer (score 1):

There is a mistake in the answer you posted. When $u_i = x_i^2 + y_i$ for $i\in \{A, B\}$, set of efficient allocations (along the contract curve) does not satisfy MRS$_A$ = MRS$_B$. This is because the utility functions are strictly quasi-convex. For example: An allocation $\left((x_A, y_A), (x_B, y_B)\right) = \left((10,10), (10, 10)\right)$ is not Pareto efficient because $\left((x_A', y_A'), (x_B', y_B')\right) = \left((\sqrt{110},0), (20-\sqrt{110}, 20)\right)$ is Pareto superior to it. Efficient allocations will be a subset of the boundaries of the Edgeworth box. As an exercise try and find them.